# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__15'

Tags: python

hello to every one, I want ro run camshift algorithm but an error is created during running time. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\code\extra algorithms\Camshift in OpenCV.py", line 11, in <module>
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w] TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__10'
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the relevant parts of your code so others can examine it and answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `frame` is None. So you can't index it like you're doing in `frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]`. You should initialize the variable or handle the case when it's None.